# manage text size in android for multiple devices

Tags: android, textview

How to manage text size for different devices at run time. I try to use this but there is no change. in dimen folder i have set

```
<dimen name="textsize">21sp</dimen>
```

and run time i used:

```
txt_font_change.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.textsize));
```

can any one help me?

thanx and regards.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it is working or not ?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to set dimens programatically: Used dimens.xml for set textsize for all android device resolutions.

In your xml file :

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/txt_day_count"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:text="1"
     android:textColor="@color/black"
     android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
     android:textStyle="bold" />
```

In values folder values-hdpi => dimens.xml(480x800)

```
<dimen name="text_size">20dp</dimen>
```

In values folder values-mdpi => dimens.xml(320x480)

```
<dimen name="text_size">16dp</dimen>
```

In values folder values-sw360dp-notlong-hdpi => dimens.xml(540x960)

```
<dimen name="text_size">21dp</dimen>
```

In values folder values-sw360dp-xhdpi => dimens.xml(720x1280)

```
<dimen name="text_size">23dp</dimen>
```

In values folder values-sw360dp-notlong-xhdpi => dimens.xml(768x1280)

```
<dimen name="text_size">24dp</dimen
```

In values folder values-sw360dp-notlong-xxhdpi => dimens.xml (1080x1920)

```
<dimen name="text_size">27dp</dimen
```

Comment: this one is good but i don`t want to manage so many xml files . so i just want set at one side and programatically detect in all devices.

Comment: if you want to set textSize programatically then you have to check different condtions for different size of devices.

Comment: i want set for 1080x1920 device